# ee$Reducer$mean: Extract mean several bands/indices with GEE in R

Tags: r, rgee

I'd like to get `"B2","B3","B4","B8","NDVI","SAVI" and "TVI"` average data from `COPERNICUS/S2_SR` collection by date/tile. I like to extract these bands and vegetation indices mean inside my ROI and I create a `s2_clean` function for bands selection and indices creation but doesn't work.
I try to do:

```
# Packages
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rgee)
    library(sf)
    ee_Initialize(drive=TRUE)
    
    # Function for remove cloud and shadows ------------------------------------------
    getQABits <- function(image, qa) {
      # Convert decimal (character) to decimal (little endian)
      qa <- sum(2^(which(rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(qa), "")) == 1))-1))
      # Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the qa value.
      image$bitwiseAnd(qa)$lt(1)
    }

    # Selection of bands and vegetation indices ---------------------------------------
    s2_clean <- function(img) {
    # Select NDVI
    img_band_selected <- img$select("B[2-4|8]")
    
    # quality band
    ndvi_qa <- img$select("QA60")

    # Select pixels to mask
    quality_mask <- getQABits(ndvi_qa, "110000000000")
    
    # Mask pixels with value zero.
    img_band_selected$updateMask(quality_mask)
    
    # Lists of bands and vegetation indices
  B2 <- img$select("B2") 
  B3 <- img$select("B3") 
  B4 <- img$select("B4") 
  B8 <- img$select("B8")
  NDVI <- img_band_selected$select("B8")$subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$divide(img_band_selected$select("B8")$add(img_band_selected$select("B4")))
  SAVI <- 1.5*img_band_selected$select("B8")$subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$divide(img_band_selected$select("B8")$subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$add(0.5))
  TVI <- 0.5$multiply(120$multiply(img_band_selected$select("B8")$subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4")))-(200*(img_band_selected$select("B3")$subtract(img_band_selected$select("B2")))))
              select<- c(B2,B3,B4,B8,NDVI,SAVI,TVI)
              return(selected)
    }

      
    # Define a Region of interest
    roi <-ee$Geometry$Point(-52.19032,-30.25413)$buffer(500)
    
    # Sentinel-2 MSI dataset into the Earth Engine’s public data archive ------------              
    s2 <- ee$ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    
    # Select S2 images ---------------------------------------------------------------
    s2_roi  <- s2$
      filterBounds(roi)$
      filter(ee$Filter$lte("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 1))$
      filter(ee$Filter$date(as.character(as.Date("2019-12-04")), as.character(as.Date("2020-05-03"))))$
      map(s2_clean)
    
    s2_roi_add_area <- s2_roi$map(
      function(img) {
        img$set("area", img$clip(roi)$geometry()$area())
      }
    )
    
    #Extract average NDVI values 
    ee_mean<- ee_extract(
     x = s2_roi_add_area,
     y = roi,
     scale = 10,
     fun = ee$Reducer$mean(),
     via = "drive"
    )
    ee_mean
```

But I always have as output:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : RuntimeError: Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

Plaese, any help with it?

Comment: your issue is with `select(c("B2","B3","B4","B8","NDVI","SAVI","TVI"))`. I think you are missing a `$` somewhere. The error lets you know that you are using select with a character vector, which is not the correct use of the function.

Comment: also you have an issue with `return(selected)`. You never define selected, so there is nothing to return. Insread do you mean, `selected<- c(B2,B3,B4,B8,NDVI,SAVI,TVI)`? Note that this does not use quotes in the vector

Comment: Thanks @AndS., but I try to do it, but now I have `Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : RuntimeError: Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in the s2_clean() function you use the $ operator on numbers, the correct equations should be:

```
SAVI <- img_band_selected$select("B8")$
subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$
divide(img_band_selected$select("B8")$
subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$
add(0.5))$multiply(1.5)

TVI <- img_band_selected$select("B8")$
subtract(img_band_selected$select("B4"))$
multiply(120)$
subtract(img_band_selected$select("B3")$
  subtract(img_band_selected$select("B2"))$
  multiply(200))$
multiply(0.5)
```